# Incorrect loading of CSV Tilemap (tmx file) using Cocos2d-x v4 C++

Tags: c++, tiled, tmxtiledmap, cocos2d-x-4.0

I am attempting to load a 2d tiled map (.tmx + .tms files) generated from Tiled Map Editor into Cocos2d-x version 4. I am building the project using Visual Studios 2022 -- Win32

I'm trying to make the scene as simple as possible, and the tiled map to be as simple as possible to just get it to work, -- to no avail.

Below is the full code of the Scene I'm trying to load:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class TileTestScene : public Scene
{
public:
  virtual bool init() 
  {
    auto map = TMXTiledMap::create("tmx/Trees.tmx");
    layer = map->getLayer("Trees");

    auto mapSize = layer->getLayerSize();

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < mapSize.width; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < mapSize.height; ++j)
      {
        auto sprite = layer->getTileAt(Vec2(i, j));
        
        if (!sprite)
        {
        
        }
      }
    }

    this->addChild(map);

    map->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2.0f, visibleSize.height / 2.0f);

    return true;
  }

  CREATE_FUNC(TileTestScene)
private:
  TMXLayer* layer;
};
```

Below is the Trees.tmx file generated by Tiled Editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.10" tiledversion="1.10.1" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-up" width="4" height="4" tilewidth="34" tileheight="34" infinite="0" nextlayerid="2" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="trees.tsx"/>
 <layer id="1" name="Trees" width="4" height="4">
  <data encoding="csv">
1,7,4,2,
3,8,5,6,
1,7,4,2,
3,8,5,6
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

And below is trees.tsx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset version="1.10" tiledversion="1.10.1" name="trees" tilewidth="34" tileheight="34" tilecount="9" columns="3">
 <image source="trees.png" width="102" height="102"/>
</tileset>
```

And image to the right is Trees.png, referenced by the tsx file:
[image: Trees.png]

In the tiled map editor, my map should look like the following (when zoomed in):
[image]

But, when then running Cocos2d-x-4 I get the following completely wrong output:
[image]

---

One thing of note which I found during debugging, which I cannot understand is the on the code line of:

```
 auto sprite = layer->getTileAt(Vec2(i, j));
```

it sometimes returns back NULL sprites, even though there are no blank tiles on my map. I'm unsure if I have set something up incorrectly for Cocos2d-x or something else. Please help

---

**UPDATE:**

Cocos2d-x fails load the file properly because Tiled Editor version 1.10 added in newline characters in the csv data, -- breaking the Cocos2d-x importing the data.

Changing Tiled Editor to export data in base64 works. -- However, I would still like the csv format to work too.

Comment: I have confirmed that the problem is that the new Layer CSV data generated by Tiled Map editor, -- which has whitespace in it, -- breaks the importer for Cocos2d-x-4

Comment: Did you debug the execution of the code and follow it into the `TMXMapInfo::endElement()` function?  See what happens when it gets to CSV handling section.  You could also change the output encoding to base64, instead of CSV, and check if that works.

Comment: This PR should contain the fix for this issue: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/20483

Comment: Yes, changing output encoding to base64 does work for sure, -- but I would like to get CSV working as it is useful for debugging and such

Comment: I'll have a look at that git post, -- but if you respond to the post with a full answer, -- ill give you credit! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As requested, moving my initial comment to a full response.)

There is a fix that exists for this issue here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/20483

You can merge the changes in that PR to address your problem.

Original fix:

```
void TMXMapInfo::endElement(void* /*ctx*/, const char *name)
{
...
        else if (tmxMapInfo->getLayerAttribs() & TMXLayerAttribCSV)
        {
            unsigned char *buffer;

            TMXLayerInfo* layer = tmxMapInfo->getLayers().back();

            tmxMapInfo->setStoringCharacters(false);
            std::string currentString = tmxMapInfo->getCurrentString();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32)
            // Fix bug when tilemap data is in csv format.
            // We have to remove all '\r' from the string
            currentString.erase(std::remove(currentString.begin(), currentString.end(), '\r'), currentString.end());
#endif

...
}
```

One thing that doesn't make sense about that fix though is that it seems to apply only to the Windows build of Cocos2d-x, but you want it to be applied to any platform, so it may be best not to use the pre-processor check for the platform (the `#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32)`).

A somewhat better fix for this issue exists in Axmol (a fork of Cocos2d-x v4), which you can also apply.  This change replaces all "\n\r" end-line characters that exist in the file, which fixes any issues related to the end of line characters.  You can see the fix here: https://github.com/axmolengine/axmol/commit/ed3bb5eaf82ba4e74dc9784da57f621d8501aff6

It's just adding `text = std::regex_replace(text, std::regex("[\n\r ]"), "");` to the `TMXMapInfo::textHandler` function.

```
void TMXMapInfo::textHandler(void* /*ctx*/, const char* ch, size_t len)
{
    TMXMapInfo* tmxMapInfo = this;
    std::string text(ch, 0, len);
    text = std::regex_replace(text, std::regex("[\n\r ]"), "");

    if (tmxMapInfo->isStoringCharacters())
    {
        std::string currentString{tmxMapInfo->getCurrentString()};
        currentString += text;
        tmxMapInfo->setCurrentString(currentString);
    }
}
```